# Sending to uithread from findinbackground

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I just wanted to know if there was a way to send something to the ui thread after doing something in the background.

```
 qUserActivity.findObjectsInBackground(block: {(objects, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
        }else {
            total = (objects?.count)!
            total = 1

        }
        //Update the ui thread here?
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

**swift 2.2**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
            //your ui code here 
        })
```

**swift 3.0**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
            // your ui code here
        })
```

So in your code:

```
qUserActivity.findObjectsInBackground(block: {(objects, error) in
    if error != nil{
        print(error)
    }else {
        total = (objects?.count)!
        total = 1


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
           self.myLabel.text = "something" 
        }) 
    }
})
```

Comment: This can be applied to parseQueries?

Comment: Use this code inside parseQueries in the position of your comment. I guess you can do this. I didn't test.

Comment: I changed my answer to illustrate how to add the code.